# Survival Analysis to Forecast Attrition

Tags: survival, model, cox-model

I have 5 years of historical data. I need to build an model forecasting attrition for the next 3-5 years. I want to build a survival analysis model, but need to know if I can estimate the attrition (if they left and time) for each observation in my data. Will the output of the Cox Survival Model allow me to do that?

Ideally, I would like to append two columns to the data set for each unique id. 1. Did they attrit? 2. When?

Comment: Have you taken a look at lifelines [here](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?  This should have some good information for you.

Comment: Thank Demetri, I can't find an answer to my specific question.

Comment: Do you think we need an exponential model because it provides a y-intercept? That way we can manually calculate the likelihood of attrition for each observation. I think that would mean the Cox model wouldn't work, but an exponential regression would work.

Comment: no a cox regression should be fine if you want to model attrition.  I suggest you familiarize yourself a little more with survival analysis.  Its the best tool for the job

Answer (score 0):

I think this chapter could be quite helpful to you: http://peopleanalytics-regression-book.org/survival.html. It focuses specifically on HR-related analyses, which should translate to what you are trying to do here.

One clarification that may be helpful: your input data should already tell you which employees left, and when. The goal of survival analysis in this context is to take that data and create a *probability model* that can be used to answer questions such as: "given the pattern of past employee behaviour, what is the probability that a new employee will still be with us in 1 year? Or 2 years, or 3 years, etc.

Another thing I would note: if you have no predictor variables, you could just use a Kaplan-Meier curve, instead of the Cox model. There's slightly less overhead in learning how that works.